# how install meilisync on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, meilisearch

Meilisearch was already deployed on EC2, how can i integrate Meilisync to sync from RDS with a Postgres database

I deployed Meilisearch and Meilisync through two different methods:

1. I created an EC2 instance using a Meilisearch image and attempted to run Meilisync via Docker.
2. I created two Docker containers for Meilisearch and Meilisync within an Ubuntu EC2 instance.
   both methods got "TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with **aiter** method, got coroutine"